# My joint make cracking sounds while I am turning my arm

Tags: grammar

My joint make cracking sounds while I am turning my arm.

When turning my arm during exercise, my joint making crack sounds. 
Does the sentence above have any grammar mistake?

Comment: Yes, both sentences do. I suggest you ask this question at [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following:

> My joint make cracking sounds while I am turning my arm.

The phrase "my joint" is **singular**, but "make" is a third person **plural** verb. Either of these would be fine, depending on the meaning you're trying to convey:

- My joints make cracking sounds while I am turning my arm.
- My joint makes cracking sounds while I am turning my arm.

In the second sentence you provided:

> When turning my arm during exercise, my joint making crack sounds.

The word "making" alone cannot be used not a verb. Instead "is making", "was making", "will be making", or perhaps even "will have been making" should be used. Again, the choice depends on what meaning you're trying to convey.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using for your first example:

> *My joints make cracking sounds while I am turning my arm*.

Or

> *My joints make cracking sounds as I turn my arm.*

- For your second example:

> *When turning my arm during exercise, my joints make cracking sounds*.

Or

> *When I turn my arm during exercise, my joints make cracking sounds*.